# Server application key fails for specific server

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api

To be clear, when I say "doesn't work", I meant that it returns a json object with a status of "REQUEST_DENIED". I always get a response.

I have a server key setup for the Geocode api, and I'm having an issue where it doesn't work with only one server. I've been using it locally (whitelisted my ip) without issue, and tested it with cURL on a Digital Ocean vps without issue.

On a WP Engine server, however, I cannot get it working. I've added the IP address and spent over and hour with their tech support verifying that it's the right address and there's nothing funny going on. They've used cURL from their command-line as well, but it doesn't work. I tried creating a new key just for that ip, and it still didn't work. I tried a 16-bit IP range, but no dice.

Can someone please shed some light on this? I wish Google provided a list of request IP's in the report so we could verify it's getting the expected IP. Is it possible that the IP was blacklisted by this point somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Turned out I had to add the ipv6 to the allowed ips.

Comment: Greetings! I got really excited when I saw this answer, but unfortunately the host isn't using IPv6 just yet, so that can't be the issue. Thanks, though!